# Events not caught by Controller

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to respond to a view-fired event inside a controller. The event does fire, but the controller action is never called.

*View*:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Dashboard", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'my_dashboard',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'dataview',
                listeners: {
                    itemtap: function(sender, index, elem, record) {
                        // fires with param, e.g. 'inbox'
                        this.fireEvent(record.get('name'));
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
```

*Controller*:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Dashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            'my_dashboard': {
                'inbox': 'showInbox',
                ...
            }
        }
    },

    showInbox: function () {
        /* never gets called */
    },

    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I found a solution, but it feels very hacky. I added a `bubbleEvents` config to the dataview *and* the `my_dashboard` view, and the events started making their way up to the controller.

Since the dashboard can have a variable number of items, I don't know which events I need to bubble up. Of course, I could bubble up all possible dashboard events, but that just seems like a massive kludge.

Should the view fire an application event instead, e.g. `MyApp.app.fireEvent()`?

Comment: I'm not sure but it's might be a scope issue. Maybe the event is fired on the dataview and not on you my_dashboard container. Try this : `'my_dashboard dataview': { 'inbox': 'showInbox', ... }`.

Comment: @TDeBailleul: Yes, that is exactly what's happening, and my current fix is to fire the event from the `my_dashboard` level (with `this.parent.fireEvent()`).  I thought of using a more specific selector in the controller, but I don't want the controller to have to know about the internal structure of the view.

Comment: So problem solved ? Any particular reason you don't want your controller to know the internal structure of the view ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put an [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-itemId) on the dataview.

```
itemId: 'my_dashboard_dataview'
```

Then in your controller...

```
control: {
            '#my_dashboard_dataview': {
                'itemtap': 'showInbox',
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Here is some code that should get you started:

*Controller:*

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Dashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            'my_dashboard': {
                painted: 'onDashboardPainted',
                inbox: 'showInbox'
            }
        }
    },

    onDashboardPainted: function(dashboard, eOpts) {
        dashboard.down('dataview').on('itemtap', function(sender, index, elem, record){ 
          dashboard.fireEvent(record.get('name'));
          //check the console to make sure you the value is: inbox
          console.log(record.get('name'));
        });
    },

    showInbox: function () {
        console.log('showInbox init');
    },
```

---

This is definately a scope issue... in your controller add a painted function for my_dashboard... the first function variable will be the my_dashboard component itself:

```
painted: function(dashboard,...
```

Now in the painted function add the listener dynamically:

`dashboard.down('dataview').on(` ... rest of listener code ...

Now inside of the listener do `dashboard.fireEvent(....);`

Sorry for the formatting im on my mobile, if u cant get it to work i will post code tomorrow